# 3d view turning problem

Tags: 3d-view

When I am in 3d view turning by pressing the scoll button doesn't work most of the time.
Sometimes it works and 1 sec later is doesn't anymore.
my mouse is working fine and the scroll button is working fine.
I have blender 2.72
I hope this is enough information

does somebody know how to fix it?

Comment: you should try this with a different mouse and if it continues then it falls in the category of a bug report.  
https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/create/?project=2&type=Bug

Comment: okay. I will try another mouse